# Can you help me?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

> I need to get some milk,
>   can you help me pick some up?
>   I also need some vegetables
>   you need to carry them for me.
>   Antony, I need your help.

Only hint that will be given:

> You will need to use the allusion.

Comment: BTW, there actually is an answer.

Comment: Well, I would hope there would be :P

Comment: For whoever suggested the edit, there is no steganography.

Comment: Is this too hard?

Comment: It is perhaps a little bit too enigmatic, for me at least.

Comment: I'm not quite sure of what we are supposed to do, and I know that that is the point of an enigmatic puzzle but this is perhaps a bit too enigmatic in the sense of no-one knows where to start. It looks to me like a riddle, but I have no idea if it is or not...

Comment: I get that you've added [tag:reference-request] as a hint, but it's actually an invalid tag for this puzzle and should be removed...

Comment: @Alconja Sorry! I fixed it. I also updated the hint.

Comment: The only allusion I’m getting is Cleopatra speaking to Marc Antony? Cleopatra bathed in milk sometimes.

Comment: @tyobrien You were correct in Marc Antony, but not in Cleopatra. Who was Marc Antony serving most of his life?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be

> A Caesar salad.

From hints in the comments,

> "Antony" references Marc Antony, who was a general under Julius Caesar.
>  A Caesar salad uses Parmesan cheese (which is made from ***milk***) in the dressing and as a topping.
>  It also uses lettuce, a ***vegetable***.  (And in some cases, tomato is also used.)